# Why is the function which seems to be returning print declared Void?

Tags: swift

The code in question is below:

```
  class Singer {
    func playSong() {
        print("Shake it off!")
    }
}

func sing() -> () -> Void { // Void???
    let taylor = Singer()

    let singing = {
        taylor.playSong()
        return
    }

    return singing
}


 let singFunction = sing()
    singFunction()
```

Bonus question: I didn't quite understand declaration:

```
func sing() -> () -> Void
```

Couldn't we just declare it as?:

```
func sing() -> Void
```

Comment: `sing` returns function, which returns nothing. `() -> Void` is function declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read the declaration of `sing` as:

```
func sing() -> (() -> Void)
```

which means that `sing` returns "*a function that returns nothing* i.e. `() -> Void`". `sing` doesn't return `Void`, it returns another function. That returned function does whatever it needs to do, and does not return a value, hence `Void`.

The function being returned here is `singing`, which calls `taylor.playSong()`.

You could declare `sing` to return `Void`, instead of `() -> Void`, but you'd also have to edit its body:

```
func sing() {
    let taylor = Singer()
    taylor.playSong()
}
```

Since `sing` can't return another function now, it can only call `taylor.playSong()` directly.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't return `Void`, it returns a closure with no arguments and no return value. This is the same as an anonymous function.